# How to not rerender all RadListView items

Tags: angular, performance, nativescript, radlistview

I see ObservableArray is used in all docs of RadListView and i see not remote datasource example: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/master/listview/src/app/examples

I wonder does ObservableArray plays some big role in not rerendering all items / in updating just one item etc. like in plain angular with *ngFor trackBy only item that changed is rerendered?

Problem is that when i have my list items in state and i update even one item - all items are rerendered and radlistview again becomes slow while it scrolls.

Comment: ObservableArray is nothing but a simple array, fires some events to help the components to detect changes and update the view. If I'm not wrong it was originally developed to help NativeScript Core users, Angular already manages change detection well with simple arrays. Refer load on demand examples, which shows you how you may update array with new items.

Comment: I know how i can update array with new items - my worry is that after updating array with new items whole list is re-rendered. When using *ngFor with trackBy whole list is not re-rendered. Or you are rying to say if i will be using onDemand technique NS will not re-render whole list?

Also - problem of re-rendering is on not only adding items but on updating existing item too. Do you think using notifyLoadOnDemandFinished will solve it too?

Comment: If doesn't render whole list if you push items not change the reference. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: I see, but then i have to call cd.detectChanges() right? Instance is changing because i am using state management. However Angular, with ngFor and trackBy, is able to handle re-rendering even with reference change - cannt it be applied in RadListView also?

If it cannot be applied then all state management libs like NgRx are useless - then code sharing with angular also is useless...

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is that when i have my list items in state and i update even
>   one item - all items are rerendered and radlistview again becomes slow
>   while it scrolls.

This usually means you're doing something wrong with `ObservableArray`. When you add an item, use `push()` and it won't re-render the whole list just a new item should appear. I've been there and could solve the RadListView issues with using ObservableArray as expected.

Please, share a sample here if you need a more specific answer:
https://play.nativescript.org/

Comment: This means that i am not using observableArray and not using local state and local items. I am using global immutable state which, on every modification, creates new refs - this is how Redux, NgRX, @ng-state/store and all other works.

Comment: You're wrong. You're about using RadListView which should be used with ObservableArray. If you don't do it, you shouldn't be surprised it doesn't work as you expect :) Use the component the way as it described in the documentation and you'll be good. Easy

Comment: Heh. ObservableArray was designed just to make NS life easier (You can read it in comments above). Angular *ngIf takes advantage of trackByFn so no matter if object ref is new or not it DOES not rerender existing not changed items. React has virtual DOM which allows React to do the same. We have different view and opinions on this @peter and thats fine. If i am wrong then global state management is not possible with NS and RadViewList or you have to do remappings to local ObservableArray which makes global state kind of useles again.

Comment: Your original question is, the whole list re-renders when you add an item. If you use ObservableArray this doesn't happen, it works on my phone with my app, I can add and remove items without re-render :)

Comment: Exactly - but then, after manoj explanation, i rised another concenr that this is not desired RadListView behaviour to be able to work only woth LOCAL list. Anyway it does not matter any more because I swithced from NS away.

Comment: It works with non-local list too, like async call. I use it that way :) Works not rerenders even with lazy loading and pull to refresh functions. It's perfect. If it's not perfect for you you're doing something wrong. But it does nothing if you've given up learning NS. Good luck!